# ImageViews changed positions when scrolling in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I have a very frustrating problem and I don't have an idea what is wrong.
I build simple XML which contains only GridView. This gridview should show images (ImageView) downloaded from specific urls which I retreive with my code.

So the idea of this APP is only to download images from URLS and show those images in GridView. First I must say that I'm using Universal Image Loader library. First please look at my getView code:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView iv;

        if(convertView == null) {

        iv = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size,size));
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Log.d("APP", "convertView is NULL");

        } 

        else {

        iv = (ImageView) convertView;
        Log.d("APP", "convertView is NOT null");

        }

        loader.displayImage(URLS.get(position), iv);

        return iv;

    }
```

**PROBLEM:**

Code above works, and it shows images in GridView. But when I scroll down, I see that:

1. All images were downloaded (Even those images who are not visible )
2. When i scroll back up I see that image which was in place 0, is in place 1 and it has been downloaded again. When I scroll back down, images switched positions again. Scrolling back up, I see again images are switching places again ( and downloading again). This goes infinite.

**HOW I SOLVED THIS PROBLEM:**

1. I solved this problem by NOT checking if convertView variable is null. Actually I ommited if/else clause.
2. I used cache in memory = true. So downloading stops and images are in place for ever.

So why I'm asking for help? Mainly because i know that i should not ommit if/else clause for performance reasons. I don't want to mess with users memory and I would like to bring them fast and reliable user experience. Also i would like to know what could be wrong.

Thank you for help. Much appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Loader needed some time to load picure in `ImageView`. Because you reuse view for different images you can see a previous image in the view while new image is loading.  You can set `resetViewBeforeLoading(true)` in `DisplayImageOptions` for avoid this effect.

Also you can use disk cache to avoid downloading images every time from the network. Also limit size of memory cache and set other settings, but I think memory cache is useful, it improves user experience.
And don't forget to use `setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(loader, true, true))` to avoid lags on scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

GridView recycles list items for performance purposes. So when you are scrolling, the list items are getting recycled in different places and then your code is re-populating them. Sometimes this lags for images.

I'd recommend using a library that handles this sort of thing like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But isn't this strange, because I think universal image loader was created only for that purpose. But I will look at your library.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exactly same problem as you, and didn't want to disable convertView checking either.
My solution was to increase the memory cache size in ImageLoaderConfiguration.

Before, i used to use it like this:
`.memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))`

So I changed it to:
`.memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(10 * 1024 * 1024))`

I don't know if 10*1024*1024 is too much or it will cause any problems, but it seems to have fixed the problem to me and i haven't had any problems until now.